# Dynamic Naming of Range of Excel using vba

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have two variables :

a=5
b=8

I want to define a Range like

```
'Activeworksheet.Range(a,b).select
    selection.copy
    Activeworksheet.Range((a+1),(b+a)).select
    selection.paste
    `
```

This can be done for one variable like

```
Activeworksheet.Range("E" & b).select
```

and when I am trying this

```
 Activeworksheet.Range(&a & b).select
```

Its also not working.

How to name the range dynamically using two variables.

Comment: use `Activesheet.Cells(a,b).Select`... and try to avoid `Selection` if possible!

Comment: It can't be done with help of range.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's `Activesheet` not `ActiveWorksheet`. Second you need to use the `Cells` property rather than `Range` if you have a row and column number:

```
Activesheet.Cells(a, b).select
```

where `a` is the row number and `b` the column (can be a number or letter)

Comment: I want it in a range format. If it is Possible. Otherwise, I can use cells.

Comment: Why? What difference does it make to you?

Comment: Your example is only one cell. If you need multiple, you can use `Range(Cells(x, y), Cells(j, k))` where the two cells are the top left and bottom right cells in the range you want.